# How to obtain Integrator from CMSIS arm_pid_f32

Tags: arm, signal-processing, cmsis, pid-controller

I am trying to CMSIS DSP for the first time with STM32. I am developing an application which needs the integrator (error accumulated) over time .  I am using `arm_pid_f32`
to calculate the PID error as shown below . How do I obtain just the integrator from this library or function ? Any help appreciated !

```
y[n] = y[n-1] + A0 * x[n] + A1 * x[n-1] + A2 * x[n-2]
   A0 = Kp + Ki + Kd
   A1 = (-Kp ) - (2 * Kd )
   A2 = Kd
```